# Created simple pipeline with Foreach and copy activity in it

Tags: azure-data-factory

Pipeline looks like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVrOU.png)

Getting below error while running the pipeline:
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/5d952a91-86a9-4b29-96aa-2b07c7a010a5",
"details": null,
"error": null
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2VZ.png)

Can I get help why the pipeline is not running

Comment: Please share the json code of your pipeline

Comment: what is the expression in 'Item' option in forEach activity ?

Answer (score 0):

> { "code": "BadRequest", "message": null, "target": "pipeline//runid/5d952a91-86a9-4b29-96aa-2b07c7a010a5", "details": null, "error": null }

The error is not specifying exact issue. but this error comes for the minor mistakes like incorrect values, names etc.

- Firstly, check the settings of ForEach activity in Items you are passing `Array` value. Value with any other format will give you this error.

To resolve this, create array with pipeline parameter or variable as below and pass it in ForEach activity.
[image]
[image]
Or using dynamic expression as `@createArray('sample1','sample2')`

- Check all the reference you used in pipeline are correct.